# Application lockups when connected to domain network

Tags: domain, microsoft-office-2010, user-profile

We provide IT support for a small domain environment, (2008r2 domain, exchange 2010) around 12 users, most of with are mobile. We started getting complaints from the owner (its always the owner isn't it?) that he was getting frequent outlook lockups.

Here are the details:

He works on a 1 year old Dell XPS laptop with a good SSD, Windows 7-Pro-64 SP1 fully patched and Office 2010 also fully patched.

He is the only user that is affected.

The weird part, and this is key to my needing to get some help on this, it ONLY locks up when he's plugged into the physical domain network! At home, on the road,traveling in China, on a starbucks wifi, anywhere else he has connection he doesn't have any problems. But in the office domain network it happens 5-10 times a day at least.

What we discovered:

There are 2 common triggers. He often finds things online (articles, research, etc.) and he copies the text and inline pictures, pasting them into a new email. Or opening/previewing an email with some embedded web content of some type can trigger it. He uses IE 10, but chrome yields the same results, If he copies just text it's usually fine, but as soon as he copies mixed content it locks outlook.

We found a perfect test case, blogs.office.com articles all will trigger the behavior when selecting text + photos and pasting into Outlook **or Word.**

We discovered that pasting the same things into Word actually causes that to crash as well. Blank new word document.

I say crash but its actually more of a endless hang not responding that needs to be killed. No event log errors.

Thoughts:
I would blame this on some kind of hardware issue, like the ssd, or memory, but it works fine out of the office every time.

I think its either something with content trust settings, or some aspect of security policy on temp files or clipboard.

Both I, and he understand that pasting web content isn't safe and is a bad practice. He still needs it to work. He isn't interested in workarounds.

Posting questions is usually my last stop before a Microsoft case, I owner is getting frustrated, but being patient. I can make adjustments, but I wont have options like wiping the laptop, wiping profile, etc. It needs to be a scalpel fix, not a hammer. I appreciate the help very much, and I'll be watching this thread closely for followup.

Mods: I felt the domain effect here made this more suited for Server fault, but if superuser is better feel free to move.

Update 10-08-2014: I managed to get a few minutes with the computer and sure enough, in the domain network, with DNS changed to a public DNS server (opendns) everything works, except of course all the domain resources, but it does point to something lookup related. Server here is SBS2011 technically, in case it matters. should have more time with it tomorrow.

Comment: This may come off as a pat answer, but have you checked his DNS configuration while connected in the office? Assuming the use of DHCP, is he getting the correct DNS servers while in the office?

Comment: Oh I'll take any ideas that I can get! The DNS is correct, DHCP is passing only the correct DNS for the environment(the DC), no extra servers, no gateways, or external DNS. Internal addresses resolve fine, as well as externals.

Comment: I was convinced it had something to do with the network config, or outlook mapi weirdness until we discovered that we had the same issue in Word. A copy/paste from a Browser to Word shouldn't even require the correct DNS.

Comment: It would if Word has to resolve the URL's for the page and associated links. That's what made me wonder about the DNS.

Comment: @mschietinger: I wouldn't be sure about this. I've no idea if it actually happens but I think it's absolutely possible that a copy/paste like this require a DNS lookup for metadata like IE security zones etc.

Comment: Ok, good point. Maybe the zones are managed by something on the DC, unless its unreachable, in which case they would fallback to defaults... I'd expect to see that on other systems and/or users and we aren't though. I haven't tried changing just the DNS server to a fixed public DNS, but I suspect it would work without errors.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually fixed this today. Turns out it was the skype click to call plug in for I.E.

The best I can tell, the plugin injects some code into every page to make the numbers on pages clickable, but that code must refer back to the plugin in some way. so then when the user copies to word, that link back to the plugin breaks in some way that the system can't handle.

My guess is word is trying to reconcile the plugin or skype target in some way and can't.

The only question is why does it work perfectly at home? 
Thanks joequerty, thinking about looking up the URL lead me down the right path.